# Pointer to Element in Vector

Tags: c++, qt

I am farily new to c++ and have already read some topics about storing pointers to objects or the objects themselves in a vector.
I decided to store the objects in the vector, because I do not push_back many objects at runtime, the vector is just created once and leaved like this.

My problem now is, that I have another object that gets a vector as argument and searches for a certain object in the passed vector. If it finds this object, it stores a pointer to it, if not, the variable is set to `NULL`.

Eventhough I do not `push_back` any items, the pointer seems to point to a wrong location in other functions.
The object that searches for the element in the vector has a public function in which the pointer should be returned. It would be very slow if I search for the object at every function call, so this should not be an option.
**Are there other solutions or do I have to *switch to a vector of pointers?***

Some code snippets:

**Constructor of the object that searches the vector:**

```
MySearch::MySearch(QVector<Obj> objVector)
    :objVector(objVector) {
    found = NULL
    foreach(Obj o, this->objVector) {
        if(..found..) {
            found = &o;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Getter function:**

```
Obj* MySearch::getObject() {
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be trying to remember the thing you are looking for, o, rather than anything in the vector. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @doctorlove what do you mean? Yes, I want to remember the pointer to the found object.

Comment: `foreach` is not C++, that's why i was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the variable `o` is local and will be out of scope as soon as the loop ends. If you take the address of the vector element instead of the `o`, it will works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MySearch
{
public:
  MySearch(const vector<string> &items)
    : items_(items) 
  {
    // Skipping validation
    found_ = &(items_[5]);
  }

  string *getObject() {return found_;}

private:
  vector<string> items_;
  string *found_;
};

int main()
{
  string str = "test#";
  vector<string> aux;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    aux.push_back(str + (char)('0' + i));  // test#0 ... test#9   

  MySearch ms(aux);
  cout << *(ms.getObject()) << endl; // test#5

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: He *does* keep the vector in the same class - the constructor initializer list and the use of this->objVector are the clues in the question but he should probably avoid the name ambiguity all the same.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed the constructor initializer. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Jose Rios, why is it all striked out? You shouldn't do that. Please remove the strikeouts and keep only the latest (the most correct) version of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Obj o, this->objVector) {
    if(..found..) {
        found = &o;

        break;
    }
} // life time of o ends here.
```

`o` resides on stack and it's life-time is limited to the loop only. Having reference to it and later returning causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but would it be save if I used the pointer to the object in the Vector? I think not, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you don't take the address of o, which goes away by the end of the function it will be less bad

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `BOOST_FOREACH` (from the boost C++ libraries), then you could use a non-const reference to the objects in the vector.  `Q_FOREACH` does not support non-const references:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Obj& o, this->objVector) {
    if(..found..) {
        found = &o;

        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively use iterators and a `for` loop.

Comment: oh - nobody mentioned boost for each. It still looks like pseudo code to me

Comment: I don't think `found` would be valid outside that Q_FOREACH loop, since Q_FOREACH iterates over a _copy_ of the container.

Comment: @doctorlove yes the `..found..` bit is clearly pseudocode but I was just copying what the the OP had.

Comment: @Pete Yes it does. ["Since foreach creates a copy of the container, using a non-const reference for the variable does not allow you to modify the original container. It only affects the copy, which is probably not what you want."](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword)

Comment: Yes sorry I misread the code of QForeachContainer.  Why on earth did they implement it that way.  BOOST_FOREACH is clearly preferable.  Updated my answer

Comment: However, since QVector uses implicit sharing, Q_FOREACH would actually work in the way I originally said, unless you modify the QVector itself since the iteration uses const iterators.  The required const cast is ugly though.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right... The const cast would circumvent  the copy-on-write mechanism. As for why it makes a copy? I believe foreach copies so you can emit signals within the loop without fear that you'll trigger a change to the container you're iterating over, but I've never seen an official explanation.